# Inheritance example

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, inheritance

Consider the below code snippet:

```
  class BaseClass
{
    public void SayHi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi from base class");
    }

    public virtual void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from base class");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void SayHi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi from derived class");
    }

    public new void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from derived class");
    }
}

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass _object = new DerivedClass();

        _object.SayHi();
        _object.SayHello();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output for above shows:

```
Hi from base class 
Hi from derived class
```

Can anyone please explain me the reason behind this. Also, is it not necessary to override a virtual method of base class if we are creating a method of same name in derived class?

Comment: Your output is wrong.  This should say `Hi from base class` and `Hello from base class`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of polymorphism is that an object of type `BaseClass` can be set to an instance of a `Derived` class but have different behavior [semantics].  If this wasn't the case then you'd never be able to insert a new derived Form instance into the `Winforms` framework.

OP, your definition is wrong.  Virtual methods are to enable Polymorphism.  The use of the `new` keyword is wrong too, it should be `override` to define new behavior for a `virtual` method.

Your virtual methods in your base class can be overridden in your base classes so that even if your variable type is `BaseClass`, your overridden virtual methods will be invoked on that variable.

Comment: You are viewing desire of OP? He wants to declare as `new`. Have you have something against it?

Comment: @Hamlet; nothing against it at all.  I see i may have not answered the OPs exact question.... thanks for pointing that out!  This isn't the first or last time i'll make a mistake on SO... :/   ;)